# Android: get back String matrix from Message object

Tags: android, handler, message

Here is the problem:

```
private void doSomething() {
  String[][] data = new String[h][w];
  Message msg = null;
  Thread t = new Thread() {
     public void run() {
       for(int i=0; i<max; i++) {
          data = doLongCalculationOnBackground(i);

          msg = messageHandler.obtainMessage();
          msg.obj = data;
          messageHandler.sendMessage(msg);
       }
     }
  };
  t.start();
}

private Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        doUpdateUI(msg.obj); // error right here!!!
    }

};

private doUpdateUI(String[][] data) {
   // do update UI work.
}
```

Eclipse alerts that doUpdateUI(msg.obj) is not applicable for the arguments (Object).

So how can i obtain the string matrix sent by Message object? Please don't suggest me use Async Task.

Answer (score 1):

I'm stupid, just cast argument msg.obj to String[][]:

```
doUpdateUI((String[][]) msg.obj);
```